# DateTimeImmutable 24й формат времени

Tags: php, datetime

В сущности при создании поста выставляю время с помощью DateTimeImmutable. Получаю 12 часовой формат времени, как я могу выставить 24й формат времени без временной зоны и функции которую я использую

```php
    public function format(DateTimeInterface $dateTime): string
    {
        //return $dateTime->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z');
        return $dateTime
            ->setTimeZone(new \DateTimeZone('Europe/Moscow'))
            ->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:sT');
    }
```